# Restkit map single string

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

I would like to know if is it possible to map jsons that aren't objects.

For example, I have WebService that are returning just simple values without a key:

`[true]`  Or  `[1]`

So, when restkit tries to parse this results crashes. For the first example, this the log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<__NSCFBoolean 0x2f6ead8> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key result.'

The trouble that I have is that I can't modify the WebService.

Comment: Why you need restkit for that? You don't need to parse anything, just use a simple NURLRequest...

Comment: Either don't use Restkit, or you should be using the HTTP status code to convey the success (and mapping to null).

Comment: @JavierFloresFont because, for example, I am calling a login WS if the login is sucessfull the WS returns the user data that I need to parse, but if the login data is wrong I just get a [0]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but they must have a key to them.
Thats a bad JSON formatting. If you want to return a boolean in a JSON it should look like this:

```
{
    "IS_TRUE": 1
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it is a bad json formatting, but as I said, I can't modify the WS so I just have to work with that.